# Cannot use LibHaru because cannot find the reference of zlib

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, zlib, libharu

I am trying to build a program that will hopefully create dynamic .pdf files. I have actually developed a similar project with PHP for web, but now I want to write it with C++.

This resulted me to rebuild those three libraries (zlib, libpng and libharu) more than time times for the last four days. I have read all the relevant entries in the web (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242866/i-am-getting-a-strange-errors-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-deflate) stack overflow entry) I understood that my problem is that the compiler cannot find zlib (maybe I understood the problem wrongly)

I want to explain what I've done. Please note that I'm using Codeblocks IDE with GNU GCC C++ Compiler (MingGW) in Windows 7. First, I compiled zlib 1.2.7 and created my zlib.a static library file (I'm using static libraries). Secondly, I compiled libpng 1.5.13 and created my libpng.a. Thirdly, I compiled libharu (snapshot) and created my libharu.a static library file. Then I added those library files to my project. (I did everything explained in [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/)). And at last, compiled my project.

Well, I shall say I did those all steps more than ten times, changing some small things, but everytime I am getting an error. I have even tried the official examples in libharu.org.
The most weird thing is that my error is NOT stable. Nearly everytime I got different errors! But mostly it was related with hpdf_streams.c.
My recent log file:

```
C:\Libs\libharu-201301131604\libharu.a(hpdf_streams.o):hpdf_streams.c:(.text+0xd4a): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
C:\Libs\libharu-201301131604\libharu.a(hpdf_streams.o):hpdf_streams.c:(.text+0xdfa): undefined reference to `deflate'
C:\Libs\libharu-201301131604\libharu.a(hpdf_streams.o):hpdf_streams.c:(.text+0xe78): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
C:\Libs\libharu-201301131604\libharu.a(hpdf_streams.o):hpdf_streams.c:(.text+0xee2): undefined reference to `deflate'
C:\Libs\libharu-201301131604\libharu.a(hpdf_streams.o):hpdf_streams.c:(.text+0xf7e): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
C:\Libs\libharu-201301131604\libharu.a(hpdf_streams.o):hpdf_streams.c:(.text+0xfb7): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
C:\Libs\libharu-201301131604\libharu.a(hpdf_streams.o):hpdf_streams.c:(.text+0xff1): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
```

Comment: In what order did you list the libraries? The correct order would be `-lharu -lpng -lz`, or the linker might not think zlib is being used.

Comment: James McLaughlin, oops I though it should be -lz -lpng -lharu since lharu will need lz and lpng; and lpng will need lz. I will fix it, thank you :)

Comment: Yes, it's a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: Unfortunately, I works for zlib, but now it gives errors about pngtest.c when I add <windows.h> and declare int WINAPI WinMain(...), should I compile libpng without this file (pngtest.c) Can I edit my question according to this?

Comment: It's probably best if you just open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

We just had this issue. You need to recompile zlib with WIN_API off. Or use the dll's and not the static library.