# Libharu creates errors about pngtest.c with windows.h

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, libpng, libharu

I have faced with an easy-solvable problem with libharu which I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303851/cannot-use-libharu-because-cannot-find-the-reference-of-zlib#comment19870745_14303851); but unfortunately when I fixed the first problem, a second one appeared.
I'm using Codeblocks IDE with GNU GCC C++ Compiler (MingGW) in Windows 7. I compiled libharu.a, libpng.a and zlib.a and linked them to my main project in correct order. Consequently, it compiles well and creates my .pdf
However, when I add

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
//Insert further code here...
}
```

to my codes it gives an amount of errors related with libpng, specificly pngtest.c. When I simply interchange "int WINAPI WinMain(...)" with "int main" everything runs okay (of course except it runs in terminal) and creates the correct .pdf file.
My log file:

```
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x236): undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to `png_set_error_fn'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x2b4): undefined reference to `png_set_read_status_fn'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `png_read_info'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x314): undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x33c): undefined reference to `png_get_PLTE'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `png_get_rowbytes'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `png_malloc'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x39c): undefined reference to `png_read_rows'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x3b7): undefined reference to `png_read_end'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x3cb): undefined reference to `png_free'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x3ef): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x54c): undefined reference to `png_set_PLTE'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x5a0): undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x5bc): undefined reference to `png_set_read_status_fn'
C:\Libs\libpng-1.5.13\libpng.a(pngtest.o):pngtest.c:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `png_error'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the console when using gcc, just add -mwindows to the linker flags.
WinMain() is not necessary.

Comment: Now I see that the problem is coming from pngtest.o.
Remove it, it's really just for testing.
It's an application itself, so now you have 2 different main() functions.